# Sqlite connection string in AppData folder. Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm making an application which use the sqlite as localdb.

I want to save the databse within the appdata file of the user.

Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cctv_tech.Models
{
    class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Setting> Settings { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=mydb.db;"); 
            // this is working, but database file is within the debug folder

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=c:\\mydb.db;");
            // this output me an error which the database cannot be open,
            // and when checked there is no such file
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SQLite Error 14]

Hope someone can help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the first case, your database will be in the bin folder after publish. There is only Debug folder during development. In second case, you could try [the Application Data special folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @Crowcoder  `string dbPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData); optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + dbPath);` Also give me the error "unable to open database"

Comment: @Crowcoder I know what is wrong. I forget to put the database file name. Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the main program you were just missing:

```
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
       var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>();
       context.Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
```